# In BillingClient setup .setListener(this) references my calling activity instead of a PurchasesUpdatedListener

Tags: in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, billing, billingclient

The docs show the following for setting up a Billingclient.

```
private BillingClient billingClient;
...
billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(activity).setListener(this).build();
```

In .setListener(this), the 'this' part is supposed to reference a PurchasesUpdatedListener, even though you don't explicitly create one to put in these parenthesis. Apparently just using 'this' is supposed to be enough. In the docs and all the examples I've seen, a PurchasesUpdatedListener is never created to put here, it just uses 'this', apparently self-referencing the billingclient being created. This hasn't worked for me though, and I keep getting:

[image]

Should I use something else for the (activity) part than (getApplicationContext())? I've tried (this) and various other things here as just the word 'activity' isn't recognized.

Answer (score 0):

Instead `setListener(this)` put `setListener(new PurchasesUpdatedListener(){... })` and implement the required methods (usually AndroidStudio does it automatically)

Or

add .. `implements PurchasesUpdatedListener` at the end of your MainActivity declaration

the same thing as you can do on many listeners, for example the well known OnClickListener

Comment: I have attempted this too, despite there being no examples of doing this in the docs, but it introduces method clash errors, an issue I'm also having with billingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener()...

Comment: it seems that more than a problem with the InApp billing library you have a problem in how to use listeners in general